# Как сохранить значение из EditText при закрытии фрагмента?

Tags: android, android-fragment

У меня есть фрагмент с `EditText`. Я ввожу в него текст. Жму кнопку. Перехожу на новый фрагмент. Текущий `Replace`.

Как мне сохранить данные, введенные в `EditText` и достать их, когда я снова вернусь на первый фрагмент?
Само собой напрашивается:

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("code", getTextField().getText().toString());
        textCode = getTextField().getText().toString();
    }
```

но он даже не вызывается.
Я почитал и узнал, что он вызывается, если я, например, сверну программу. Я проверил и да -  вызывается. Но как мне вызвать его, когда я вызываю новый фрагмент и реплейсаю им старый? Или может есть другие варианты сохранить значение? Глобальная статическая переменная, шаред преференс - как то костыльно.

Comment: Не очень понял... почему вы не можете запоминать значение в onPause? Сделайте переменную в классе фрагмента, в onPause записывайте, в onResume делайте EditText.setText(savedText);

Comment: EditText присутствует в верстке или он добавляется динамически?

Answer (score 1):

Можно создавать фрагменты с указанным параметром setRetainInstance(true). Такие фрагменты остаются при пересоздание активности. НО! Не в куем случае нельзя в таких фрагментах создавать графические элементы. Они только для хранения данных, иначе - утечка памяти.

```
public static class DataFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    private int cur_step = 0;
    ItemData itemData = null;
    String butNextText = null;
    boolean butNextEnabled = false;
}
```

В onCreate активности:

```
FragmentManager fm =  getSupportFragmentManager();
mData = (DataFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("dataMain");

if (mData == null) {
    mData = new DataFragment();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(mData, "dataMain").commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто записывайте значение в переменную активити и там же его сохраняйте при сворачивании/ повороте экрана. Соответственно при вызове/ возврате фрагмента берите ему это значение из активити:

```
yoursInFragmentVariableName=((YoursActivityClass) getActivity()).yoursSavedInActivityVaraibleName;
```

Comment: Статическая переменная глобальная, шаред преференс - как то костыльно.

Comment: В моем ответе не предполагается не первое не второе.